# rails aborted! Invalid format of target version: `VERSION=3.6.5`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, photoeditorsdk

I am playing around with PhotoEditor SDK, following their `https://docs.photoeditorsdk.com/quickstarts/rails`.

I was able to launch a first test app with SQLite to get familiar with the SDK and all was working fine.

So, I decided to give it a more serious shot, starting everything over, this time with Postgresql.

Every time I try to migrate my database with `rails db:migrate`, I get the following error:

```
rails aborted!
Invalid format of target version: `VERSION=3.6.5`
/Users/user/code/palette/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/user/code/palette/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

and here it is with the full trace:

```
rails aborted!
Invalid format of target version: `VERSION=3.6.5`
/Users/user/code/palette/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/user/code/palette/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
users-MacBook-Pro:palette user$ --trace
-bash: --trace: command not found
users-MacBook-Pro:palette user$ rails db:migrate --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
rails aborted!
Invalid format of target version: `VERSION=3.6.5`
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:182:in `check_target_version'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:167:in `migrate'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:60:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:273:in `block in execute'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:273:in `each'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:273:in `execute'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:214:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:226:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:183:in `invoke'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:23:in `block in perform'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:83:in `register'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
/Users/user/code/palette/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:70:in `require'
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:70:in `require'
/Users/user/code/palette/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

It looks like this has to do with the `export VERSION=3.6.5` command executed earlier.

Any idea what is happening and how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct, it's happening because of the `VERSION` environment variable you've set to clone the sdk. It is getting raised from here:

```
      def check_target_version
        if target_version && !(Migration::MigrationFilenameRegexp.match?(ENV["VERSION"]) || /\A\d+\z/.match?(ENV["VERSION"]))
          raise "Invalid format of target version: `VERSION=#{ENV['VERSION']}`"
        end
      end
```

After looking at [quickstart guide](https://docs.photoeditorsdk.com/quickstarts/rails) I think you need the VERSION variable just to get the sdk and after that it is not required.

So in that case you can unset the VERSION env variable and that should fix it, you can do it by running `unset VERSION`. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Indeed, no more error: that solved the issue. Thanks.